# CSS for Outlook : Table column width refuses to be set by any means

Tags: css, email, html-table, outlook

Trying to develop a nice looking email that will work in Outlook is a nightmare.

Right now I just want the column holding the user image to have a hardcoded width that never changes. I have tried several solutions found online but with no success.

See the following screenshots. I have made the `<td>`s have a purple border to show them more clearly.

Here's how it looks in gmail (correct, minus the buttons)
[image]

Here's Outlook 2019 (using Litmus.com)
[image]

Here's my HTML with styles inlined

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;line-height:1.5;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;width:368px;border-radius:2px;border:1px solid #888888;background-color:#ffffff;padding:8px;color:#0a1f44;margin-bottom:12px">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td style="border:1px solid purple;box-sizing:border-box">
            <table style="border-collapse:collapse;line-height:1.5;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td rowspan="4" style="border:1px solid purple;box-sizing:border-box;width:96px;max-width:70px">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/XgS5sKD.png" height="88" width="88" style="width:88px;height:88px" class="CToWUd">
                     </td>
                     <td style="border:1px solid purple;box-sizing:border-box;font-size:16px">John Smith</td>
                     <td rowspan="2" style="border:1px solid purple;box-sizing:border-box;text-align:right;vertical-align:top;font-size:11px">
                        5 years<br>
                        in real estate
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td style="border:1px solid purple;box-sizing:border-box;font-size:12px">(510) 555-1234</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="2" style="border:1px solid purple;box-sizing:border-box;font-size:12px"><a href="mailto:jsmith@gmail.com" style="color:#0c66ff;text-decoration:none;color:#0a1f44" target="_blank">jsmith@gmail.com</a></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="2" style="border:1px solid purple;box-sizing:border-box;font-size:12px">My Realty Corp</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="3" style="border:1px solid purple;box-sizing:border-box">
                        <table style="border-collapse:collapse;line-height:1.5;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif">
                           <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                 <td style="border:1px solid purple;box-sizing:border-box;display:inline-block;border:solid 1px #f58027;width:178px;text-align:center">
                                    <a href="#">Send Message</a>
                                 </td>
                                 <td style="border:1px solid purple;box-sizing:border-box;display:inline-block;border:solid 1px #f58027;width:178px;text-align:center;margin-left:8px">
                                    <a href="tel:5105551234" style="color:#0c66ff;text-decoration:none;color:#0a1f44;display:block;width:100%;background-color:aliceblue" target="_blank">Call</a>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you not just set `width:176px`? However I would presume this is a whitespace issue

Comment: @jbutler483 Sadly, it doesn't seem to work in Outlook.

Comment: Setting a perfect layout for email is very difficult. However, you may wish to reduce the width further